# Angular: local variable in template possible?

Tags: angular

Lets imagine this simple example. Display a string if its length is even.

```
<span *ngIf="foo ('abcd').length > 0">{{ foo ('abcd') }}</span>



foo (str : string) : string
{
    if (str.length % 2 == 0)
    {
        return str;
    }
    return "";
}
```

I think foo must be evaluated 2 times. First for the ngIf and then for the value of it.
Is there a way I can define a local variable (inside of the template! - I am aware of having a variable inside of the class but thats not the question) so I can only have  it evaluated once??

e.g. sort of

```
<span *ngIf="let myvar = foo ('abcd'); return myvar.length % 2 == 0">{{ myvar }}</span>
```

Comment: Truthfully foo is being evaluated twice for every change detection cycle. You want to keep functions out of templates entirely.

Comment: So you suggest it is best to map every single piece to a class variable?

Comment: use pipe it will prevent function re-render every time there is an change detection.

Comment: Yea this is commonly known as building a view model.

Comment: The final structure of your component will depend on what exactly you're trying to achieve. You can use piped Observables to display some strings and not others, or you can use a directive or even (in some cases) a pipe. It all depends on your use case. @Indraraj26 a pipe is recalculated for every cycle, I believe. OnPush change detection and Observables/directives is most likely the best approach.

Comment: @WillAlexander, I had similar issue in past with PIpe it will not re-render everytime there is an change detection.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62611605/method-called-in-ngfor-gets-trigger-for-multiple-times

Comment: Excellent, thanks for pointing that out! I didn’t think about the fact that as long as the input doesn’t change, the pipe isn’t recalculated.

Answer (score 2):

the `*ngIf` allow you asign the result of a function to a variable. Some like

```
<span *ngIf="fool('abcd') as value">
{{value}}
</span>
```

The problem is when the result of the function is false, null, undefined or "", because the span is not renderer (in your e.g. this has no importance). To take account in this case whe can create an object "on fly" with a property "value" whit the value of the function. So the *ngIf is always fullfilled

```
<span *ngIf="{value:fool('abcd')} as obj">
{{obj.value}}
</span>
```

Comment: Can I combine this with mutiple commands where the last is returning a boolean?

Comment: An object like `{value:false}` is always true -a simple empty object {} or an empty array is true when you use an *ngIf: `<div *ngIf="{}">I'm visible</div>`  `<div *ngIf="{value=false}">I'm visible too</div>`. But don't abuse the use of functions in .html. Sometimes is better to have a simple variable (especially if they are complex functions). Angular, when "see" a function in .html don't know if it's value has changed and execute them several times