# Angular, add unique class to ngFor loop while having an existing ngClass

Tags: angular, for-loop

I have a ngFor loop and I want to assign a unique class to each element but I have an already existing ngClass condition.

```
  <div class="b-game-card" *ngFor="let info of list" [ngClass]="{active: isActive(info)}">
    <div class="b-game-card__cover"></div>

  </div>
```

I tried adding `[ngClass]="{active: isActive(info), info.name}"`
but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is info.name a class you want to apply? If so move it over to your class attribute instead:

```html
  <div 
    class="b-game-card {{ info.name }}" 
    *ngFor="let info of list" 
    [ngClass]="{active: isActive(info)}">
      <div class="b-game-card__cover"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It works, but will have performance issues when the dataset is large enough.

Answer (score -1):

If you use ngClass you should provide a class name (string type)

In your case, in your.component.css

```
.activeClassName {
  active: true; //or whatever you want
}
```

in your.component.html (if isActive(info) is a correct method)

```
<div class="b-game-card" *ngFor="let info of list" [ngClass]="isActive(info) ? 'activeClassName' : ''">
 <div class="b-game-card__cover"></div>
</div>
```

In that way you provide correctly a string

Comment: never make a function call in a forloop from template, it runs in angular zone and makes the view iresponsive.

Comment: It's his solution. The point of the problema Is another

Comment: This is true, though if u give a well informed answer here, you should also consider to make him aware of drawbacks, that this answer implies, like having trouble with large Datasets, since function calls in a forloop get triggered a lot of times by changedetection and this will seriously impact performance. For such things run a pipe for example in order to not trigger the function on each changedetection cycle. There is already a correct answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62611605/method-called-in-ngfor-gets-trigger-for-multiple-times