# Avoid functions in template in case of ul list

Tags: angular, typescript, function, templates

How to avoid using function in the template in this case (simplified)?

**post.component.ts**

```
import { Details, Status } from 'models';

export class PostComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() pckgs: Details[];
  //...

  myFunc2(pckg: Details) {
    return pckg.status === Status.P ? 'processing' : pckg.status === Status.D ? 'finished' : '';
  }  
}
```

**post.component.html**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let pckg of pckgs; trackBy: trackId">
    <span [ngClass]="myFunc1(pckg)">{{myFunc2(pckg)}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I believe it can be similar to [method called in ngFor gets trigger for multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62611605/method-called-in-ngfor-gets-trigger-for-multiple-times) somehow , but in that example it's not ngFor="let item of **items**".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also "enrich" or adapt your `@Input() pckgs: Details[]` using a setter.

```
type PackageDetail = Details & { readableStatus: string };


public packages: Array<PackageDetail> = [];

@Input() set pckgs(pckgs: Details[]) {
   this.packages = pckgs.map((p)=> {
   return  {...p, ...{readableStatus: p.status === Status.P ? 'processing' : p.status === Status.D ? 'finished' : ''}} as PackageDetail;});
}
```

Btw, you don't have to do it in the component, perhaps you cold have some sort of mapper already in place so that the `PostComponent` simply received what it needs.

Another option could be to use a memoized function (which is what Angular does with the pure pipe behind the scenes) I saw this one in a [tweet](https://twitter.com/pkozlowski_os/status/1531327027327840256) by  Pawel Kozlowski :)

Comment: Thank you. How to use it in template then?

Comment: Just iterate the packages array.

Answer (score 1):

Use a pure pipe.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let pckg of pckgs; trackBy: trackId">
    <span [ngClass]="myFunc1(pckg)">{{ pckg | statusDisplay }}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**pipe**

```
@Pipe({ name: 'statusDisplay', pure: true })
export class StatusDisplayPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(pckg: Details): string {
    return pckg.status === Status.P ? 'processing' : pckg.status === Status.D ? 'finished' : '';
  }
}
```